# Best Method To Substract DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have the two following DataFrame :

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[10,20,30]})
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,2],'B':[10,20,30]})
   A   B
0  1  10
1  3  20
2  2  30
```

I would like substract this two DataFrame `d1 - d2`, expected result :

```
   A   B
0  1  0
1  3  -10
2  2  10
```

What is the best method to do that ?
Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**:

Using `sort_values` and `reset_index` to allign the index:

```
d2['B'] = d1['B'] - d2.sort_values('A')['B'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**Method 2**:

Or using `numpy.array` with `to_numpy` so we can ignore the miss-allignment in the index after sorting:

```
d2['B'] = d1['B'] - d2.sort_values('A')['B'].to_numpy()
```

---

**Method 3**:

We can also `map` the `A` column of `d1` to `d2` and this way allign the `B` columns in both dataframes:

```
d2['B'] = d2['B'] - d2['A'].map(d1.set_index('A')['B'])
```

**Output**

```
   A   B
0  1   0
1  3 -10
2  2  10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
d2['B']=d2.merge(d1,on='A').diff(-1,axis=1)['B_x']
print(d2)

   A     B
0  1   0.0
1  3 -10.0
2  2  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `set_index` of each dataframe to `A` and then `reset_index`:

```
d2['B'] = (d1.set_index('A') - d2.set_index('A')).reset_index(drop=True)

print(d2)
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  1   0
1  3 -10
2  2  10
```